# Force a fullscreen resolution that is not contained in display.list_modes()

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simulation for school and I'm trying to make pygame create a fullscreen display in my native resolution. However, I have a QHD screen (2560x1440), and it isn't working properly. As far as I can tell, pygame is rendering a screen at the correct resolution, but expanding it so it is scaled as if it were 1080p, so about 300-400 pixels are cut off around the edges. This causes, for example, a circle rendered at (200,200) to be completely invisible. After some research, I learned that this is because pygame doesn't officially support my resolution (it is not listed in pygame.display.list_modes()). Is there any way to force it to work? I would prefer if I could use my actual resolution instead of upscaled 1080p.

Here is the code that initializes the window:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
w = pygame.display.Info().current_w
h = pygame.display.Info().current_h
S = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, make sure in your display settings you have scaling set to 100%. This will make your text and everything smaller if you don't have it at that currently but I think Pygame windows get affected by this number for some reason.

See the below code snippet for making sure your window scales properly. Also see [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/raw/faa5879a7e6bfe10e4e5c79d04a3d2fb65d74a62/examples/prevent_display_stretching.py).

```
import pygame
from ctypes import windll

def run():
    # Force windows to ignore the display scaling value.
    windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()

    pygame.display.init()

    # Make the screen the highest resolution that will fit the screen at 100% scaling.
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(pygame.display.list_modes()[0])

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Thanks, when I turned the scaling down, it worked properly. It was at 150% by default. However, it makes it very difficult to use anything else on the computer because the display is fairly small. Do you know if there is any way to override the scaling instead of changing it manually?

Comment: Check the edit I just made. Seems like you need to use ctypes.